# Error remains once I got it while using swank-clojure

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank-clojure

I use Emacs for clojure development, because Swank-clojure is a great tool.
But once I get an error on slime-repl buffer, the error remains, though I fixed it or it's no more.

Reproducing way:

1. Create a clojure project with a leiningen. `$lein new myproject`.
2. At core.clj, define a function that `(defn f [] (+ 1 1))`
3. Start a swank-clojure. `M-x clojure-jack-in`.
4. On a slime-repl buffer, evaluate `(f)`. Of course it returns `2`.
5. On a slime-repl buffer, evaluate `(g)`. Of course it gets error `Unable to resolve symbol: g in this context`
6. After that, this error always appears when I try to evaluate anything in the slime-repl buffer.
   C-c C-k doesn't help. So I always restart Emacs.app when I got an error on slime-repl buffer.

My Environment:

Mac OS 10.7.3, Cocoa Emacs 23.4.1, clojure-mode 1.11.5(from a Marmalade), leiningen 1.7.0.

Comment: Did you confirm the error by hitting `Q` in the debugger, or did you leave it open?

Comment: @MatthiasBenkard This is what I must do. I have closed debugger with C-x k. That is my fault. Thank you very much. and... How can I your answer mark as Answer?

Comment: @user1209133 Ah. :)  You can't, since it's a comment, but I have resubmitted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to confirm an error and close the debugger, hit `Q` in the debugger window.  (There may be restarts other than the `QUIT` restart available, but this, at least, should always work.)

Comment: Thank you! It helps me a lot! I have closed debugger with C-x k. That is my fault.